# Python-meep and Meep capability questions

Tags: python, meep

So, my first entry on Stack Overflow! I really hope someone answers. This goes out to anyone generally using Meep or more specifically Python Meep for FDTD simulations.

Is it possible to include a complex value of conductivity as well as a real value(we are trying to do graphene, which has a complex component as well as a real one)? If not, I guess I could approximate it with just the real component, but I'd rather know. Also, is there a way to add surface charges in meep?  And finally, is it capable of handling strictly 2d structures without any thickness whatsoever? I think so, but I just want to check...

Comment: Welcome :) Please be clear on what you are asking; it is difficult to provide answers to overall wondering and worrying. Note also that if you have several, clearly separate questions, you can post them individually.

Comment: Also, always consider adding code.  Code always helps in getting an answer.  And you should read this to help get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/about